# How to stream video from android over rtsp

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, javacv, javacpp

I want to build an efficient streaming application for android. I came across at Java CV and Java CPP, which includes a wrapper for ffmpeg. I followed this piece of code and everthing works fine, using Wowza Streaming Server: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java

Howver, I want to stream the video to VLC Player directly, without the use of an external Streaming Server. Is there a way to stream the video over rtsp using the tools which are mentioned above? Does anyone have further information?

Thanks for your help!